# Having trouble displaying imported Excel regression data

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, import

The plot points and residual lines are not showing, hard-coded data works, and imported data does do something, just not what its supposed to

Is the table or the plot range the wrong size? I can't seem to find the location of the error.

Strangely, when I import the data locally, I don't get am error message, but the plot points and residuals still don't show.

```
t = Import[ "http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk//~ma302jh//RegressionExample.xls"];
tp = t[[1]];
t1 = Table[tp[[i]], {i, 2, Length[tp]}];
xcol = Table[t1[[i]][[1]], {i, 1, Length[t1]}];
ycol = Table[t1[[i]][[2]], {i, 1, Length[t1]}];
zcol = Table[t1[[i]][[3]], {i, 1, Length[t1]}];

Clear[DefineRSS];
DefineRSS[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
  (rss = Total[(zcol - (a*xcol + b*ycol + c)^2)];
  (a*x) + (b*y) + c)

Manipulate[
  With[{plane = DefineRSS[a, b, c]}, 
    Show[
      Plot3D[plane, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
        AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}, PlotLabel -> rss], 
      Graphics3D[{
        Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[Transpose[{xcol, ycol, zcol}]], 
        Line[Transpose[{{xcol, ycol, zcol}, 
               {xcol, ycol, plane /. Thread[{x, y} -> {xcol, ycol}]}}, {2, 3, 1}]]}], 
        PlotRange -> {{-11, 11}, {-11, 11}, {-50, 50}}]], 
  {a, -5, 5}, 
  {b, -5, 5}, 
  {c, -5, 5}]
```

So I fixed the import-from URL and I'm still getting unusual errors -- no residuals and no plane, but the rss value is being crunched.

Comment: If you just check, after the first line, you'll see that `t` is empty. May be that web page is gone? I get no result from the import. `t` comes out empty. screens shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qNMzW.png)

Comment: Without a short piece of `t`, little progress can be made.  Howsever, replacing the third line of code by `t1 = Table[t[[i]], {i, 2, tp}];` at least allows it to run with made-up data, `t = {2, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}};`.

Comment: oh no! damned import, im getting stranger results my end, obviously some kind of directory thing going on, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comment, replacing the third line of code by

```
t1 = Table[t[[i]], {i, 2, tp}];
```

allows the code to run.  With made-up data

```
t = {4, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {4, 3, 2}, {7, 6, 5}};
```

it produces

[image]

Is this what you had in mind?  Further progress requires actual data.

**Update**

Now that the data is available, I see that it does not have a structure consistent with the code, although this is easily fixed.  Just replace the second and third lines by

```
tp = Length[First@t];
t1 = Table[t[[1, i]], {i, 2, tp}];
```

Additionally, the scale of the data is such that the points do not appear in the figure.  Hence, I arbitrarily rescaled the points by 0.1:

```
xcol = Table[t1[[i]][[1]]/10, {i, 1, Length[t1]}];
ycol = Table[t1[[i]][[2]]/10, {i, 1, Length[t1]}];
zcol = Table[t1[[i]][[3]]/10, {i, 1, Length[t1]}];
```

You should use an appropriate rescaling.  In any case, with my rescaling, the output becomes

[image]

Comment: Yes it is what I had in mind, strangley though I think the table is being found, but now its not displaying

Comment: I see thank you so much, I have to jsut find a rescaling that works now I guess.